# LinkedIn OAuth2 Authorization Code is empty

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Yet another issue with LinkedIn OAuth2.

For a few days now, we have been receiving dozens of OAuth2 responses every day with an empty `code` parameter (as per https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2).

There is no `error` parameter provided, which means that the application has been approved by the user. Only an empty `code` parameter, and the `state` parameter (which is not empty and seems ok).

Has anyone encountered this issue? What should we do to fix that? Can we even? It is having a very bad impact on our website, as LinkedIn is the only registration method that we chose to offer, for quality reasons.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you requesting the full profile? It doesn't say in the documentation, but you need special authorization from LinkedIn to do that. If you request the basic profile only, it'll return the code.

Comment: No I'm not, I'm only getting basic profile information. In any case, the problem just went away without us doing anything special, even though we re-enabled the Google SSO option just in case. Thanks @BFWebAdmin for your answer!